# Kubernetes Let's Encrypt Certificate Not Issuing

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, spinnaker

I've done all required configurations as below to get certificate from letsencrypt in kubernetes, however I cannot see any certificate issued.

- Nginx-ingress install using helm

`helm install my-nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.publishService.enabled=true`

- Cert-manager installation

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jetstack/cert-manager/release-0.11/deploy/manifests/00-crds.yaml
kubectl create namespace cert-manager
helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io
helm install my-cert-manager --namespace spinnaker jetstack/cert-manager --set ingressShim.defaultIssuerName=letsencrypt-prod --set ingressShim.defaultIssuerKind=ClusterIssuer
```

- ClusterIssuer

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    email: test@test.test
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

- Ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: spinnaker-ingress
  namespace: spinnaker
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - SpinnakerApiDomain
    - SpinnakerDeckDomain
    secretName: spinnaker
  rules:
  - host: SpinnakerApiDomain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: spin-gate
          servicePort: 8084
  - host: SpinnakerDeckDomain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: spin-deck
          servicePort: 9000
```

I'm following these document:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-on-digitalocean-kubernetes-using-helm

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-cd-pipeline-with-spinnaker-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

I've gone through other URLs as well which has same steps but when I do `kubectl get certificates --all-namespaces` I cannot see any certificate issued.

Basically I'm configuring Spinnaker behind HTTPS.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: What have you specified as secretName in your ingress yaml?

Comment: @Arghya Sandhu secretName I've given as "spinnaker".

Comment: Did you create your tls secret like this: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#tlshttps?

Comment: @KFC_ No I haven't, I thought so to create but that step is not mentioned in the URL I followed, however let me try once and see how does that go. Thanks.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, with the exact same tutorial, how were you able to solve it?

Comment: @E-Kami As I have understood, Spinnaker needs proper HTTPS domain for Gate and Deck services. If we have that then may be issuing certificate with domain binding would work. It was POC work for me, so I just then went ahead without HTTPS services and did my work. I'm afraid couldn't help much here.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use your own self-signed certificate for Ingress, you have to create TLS secret.

First you have to generate self-signed certificate and private key, for example:

`openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -subj "/CN=${HOST}/O=${HOST}"`

It will prompt you for few things, like Country Name or State but you can just hit 
`Enter` to accept defaults.

Then create your tls secret:

`kubectl create secret tls <secret_name> --key key.pem --cert cert.pem`

Then you can use it in your Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: spinnaker-ingress
  namespace: spinnaker
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - SpinnakerApiDomain
    - SpinnakerDeckDomain
    secretName: <secret_name>
  rules:
  - host: SpinnakerApiDomain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: spin-gate
          servicePort: 8084
  - host: SpinnakerDeckDomain
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: spin-deck
          servicePort: 9000
```